# sync.Pool unexpected behavior

Tags: go

Getting to know the sync.Pool i wrote 2 different New methods for it:

1. Returns a slice;
2. Returns a ptr to slice;
3. Just alloc a new slice without pool (for compare performance);

Benchmarks surprised me

1. 6ns/op and 1 alloc
2. 17ns/op and 0 alloc
3. 130ns/op and 1 alloc

Please explain why is such a big difference between 1 and 3, given that both allocate memory?
And why 1st allocates?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "sync"
)

func main() {}

type MyBuffer struct {
    pool sync.Pool
}

func New() *MyBuffer {
    return &MyBuffer{pool: sync.Pool{
        New: func() any {
            buf := make([]int, 0, 128)
            return &buf
        },
    }}
}

func New2() *MyBuffer {
    return &MyBuffer{pool: sync.Pool{
        New: func() any {
            buf := make([]int, 0, 128)
            return buf
        },
    }}
}

func Fill[S ~[]E, E any](buf *S) {
    var some E
    for i := 0; i < cap(*buf); i++ {
        *buf = append(*buf, some)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAlloc(b *testing.B) {
    b.RunParallel(func(p *testing.PB) {
        for p.Next() {
            // Get buf
            buf := make([]int, 0, 128)
            // fill
            Fill(&buf)
            // Reset
            buf = buf[:0]
        }
    })
}

func BenchmarkPoolPtr(b *testing.B) {
    mb := New()
    b.RunParallel(func(p *testing.PB) {
        for p.Next() {
            // Get buf
            buf, _ := mb.pool.Get().(*[]int)
            // fill
            Fill(buf)
            // reset
            *buf = (*buf)[:0]
            // put
            mb.pool.Put(buf)
        }
    })
}

func BenchmarkPoolNoPtr(b *testing.B) {
    mb := New2()
    b.RunParallel(func(p *testing.PB) {
        for p.Next() {
            // Get buf
            buf, _ := mb.pool.Get().([]int)
            // fill
            Fill(&buf)
            // reset
            buf = buf[:0]
            // put
            mb.pool.Put(&buf)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the 1st case, the allocation is a reference to your slice. In the 3rd case, the allocation is the complete slice.
When you look the size allocated, it's 32 B/op vs 1024 B/op
so the allocation is the reference to your slice, that is not needed when your variable is a pointer.